# Foreach loop works one way but not the other

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I seem to be having some issues looping through an array of data it works one way but not the way I want it to.

I should preface that the array is characterized by two variables `$departments` and `$_UNIQUECONSTANT['departments']`. Any help getting the constant working would be great.

The Array

```
Array (
    [departments] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Support
            [description] => Support Department
        )
        [1] => Array (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => Accounting
            [description] => Accounting Department
        )
    )
)
```

The working function.

```
foreach($departments as $department){
    $department['id'];
}
```

The function I need to be working.

```
foreach($_UNIQUECONSTANT['departments'] as $department){
    $department['id'];
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is $_UNIQUECONSTANT?

Comment: The     $_UNIQUECONSTANT is the array that all system variables are stored until script exit. It is initiated by      define('_UNIQUECONSTANT',serialize(array()));

Comment: do you de-serialize the array? Because you can't loop through a serialized array, it is just a string.

Comment: I do not. If I were to add unserialize($_UNIQUECONSTANT['departments']) it doesn't appear to help.

Comment: You don't need the `$` in defined variables, and try `unserialize(_UNIQUECONSTANT)`

Comment: Okay. It seems to be returning a blank array now. Do I need to re-serialize the array when I add data to it?

Comment: I don't recommend using serialize, IMO Json is a better option. http://us1.php.net/json_encode and http://us1.php.net/json_decode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 2 methods that should work:

**Note:** I didn't test them

```
define('_UNIQUECONSTANT', serialize(array()));

$d = unserialize(_UNIQUECONSTANT);

foreach($d["departments"] as $department){
    $department['id'];
}

// Newer PHP versions
foreach(unserialize(_UNIQUECONSTANT)["departments"] as $department){
    $department['id'];
}
```

Comment: While the bottom version seems to be throwing errors, I was able to get the top one to work.